# PHP, Facebook Like Count

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I there any way to retrieve facebook like of any single post

Please help me.

I tried to search google and I got the following code

```
function facebook_count($url){

    // Query in FQL
    $fql  = "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count ";
    $fql .= " FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'";

    $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);

    // Facebook Response is in JSON
    $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
    return json_decode($response);

}

$fb = facebook_count('https://www.facebook.com/digital.inspiration');

// facebook share count
echo $fb[0]->share_count;

// facebook like count
echo $fb[0]->like_count;

// facebook comment count
echo $fb[0]->comment_count;
```

Comment: Thanks Fred-ii- and luschn

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/5791561181_10153733325296182?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

That would be the likes for one of the entries on the Page, just replace the Post ID. Of course you need to use an Access Token to make that call. You can use an App Token: App-ID|App-Secret. More information about Tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Btw, FQL is deprecated, don´t use it anymore.